# 504 after user creation with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

Working with some inherited code using devise and active admin.

I have a form to create an admin_user (email, password, password confirm) After clicking submit the browsers hangs for bit before showing me a 504. The user is created and in the db.

This issue kind of came out of nowhere. The few commits I have done didn't touch this part of the project.

Here is the code that creates the admin user form. What happens after this I am still unclear on:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do     
  menu :parent => "Sys Admin", :priority => 2  

  index do                            
    column :email                     
    column :current_sign_in_at        
    column :last_sign_in_at           
    column :sign_in_count             
    default_actions                   
  end                                 

  filter :email                       

  form do |f|                         
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
      f.input :email
      f.input :password               
      f.input :password_confirmation  
    end                               
    f.buttons                         
  end                        

  controller do
    #https://coderwall.com/p/xfrujq
    def update_resource(object, attributes)
      update_method = attributes.first[:password].present? ? :update_attributes : :update_without_password
      object.send(update_method, *attributes)
    end
  end

end   

2013/10/17 11:58:32 [error] 1609#0: *293930 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 11:58:46 [error] 1610#0: *293932 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 11:58:50 [error] 1610#0: *293934 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 11:59:23 [error] 1610#0: *293936 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 11:59:47 [error] 1610#0: *293938 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /*****/4960 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/*****/4960", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/*****/4960"
2013/10/17 11:59:48 [error] 1610#0: *293938 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /*****/assets/btn_menu_close.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/*****/assets/btn_menu_close.png", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/*****/4960"
2013/10/17 12:30:12 [error] 1611#0: *294268 open() "/home/deployer/apps/*******/current/public/assets/wufoo.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /assets/wufoo.js HTTP/1.1", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/pioneer"
2013/10/17 12:38:17 [error] 1610#0: *294379 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "POST /admin/admin_users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/admin/admin_users", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/admin/admin_users/new"
2013/10/17 12:40:05 [error] 1610#0: *294404 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /patients HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/patients", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/users/sign_in"
2013/10/17 13:14:28 [error] 1608#0: *294872 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /api/v1/*****/2018/**_*****.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/*****/2018/**_*****.json", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 13:15:45 [error] 1609#0: *295095 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /api/v1/*****/2224/**_*****.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/*****/2224/**_*****.json", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 13:17:34 [error] 1608#0: *295160 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /api/v1/medications.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/medications.json", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 13:20:51 [error] 1609#0: *295800 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /api/v1/*****/3698/**_*****.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/*****/3698/**_*****.json", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 13:58:21 [error] 1608#0: *298069 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "GET /api/v1/*****/3457/**_*****.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/*****/3457/**_*****.json", host: "www.*******.com"
2013/10/17 16:44:39 [error] 1611#0: *301472 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "POST /admin/admin_users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/admin/admin_users", host: "www.*******.com", referrer: "https://www.*******.com/admin/admin_users/new"
2013/10/17 19:09:24 [error] 1608#0: *302423 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***IP****, server: www.*******.com, request: "POST /api/v1/images/4650/upload_file.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://***IP****:8080/api/v1/images/4650/upload_file.json", host: "www.*******.com"
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace you could provide? Or possibly some of the log information? It is difficult to determine any causes with this information. Does the issue still occur when the `update_resource` is removed?

Comment: This is all I have from my dev environment - 2013/10/18 09:22:44 [error] 4017#0: *847 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: *.dev, request: "POST /admin/admin_users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/admin/admin_users", host: "local.dev", referrer: "https://local.dev/admin/admin_users/new"

Comment: Sorry, yes  it still occurs with the update_resource removed. Also, I decided to rollback to last commit before I started on the project. It is still behaving the same way. So now I am thoroughly  confused.

Comment: I added the error log from my staging environment above

Comment: Those logs appears to be web server logs indicating that the application server isn't responding in a timely fashion. Are the Rails application logs available?